# What is Hespprivs Hall?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, marauders-map

We recently got some *Harry Potter* themed wallpaper for our downstairs toilet in the style of the Marauder's Map. Everything seems normal about it except for one room named on it as "Hespprivs Hall" (which actually returns no results on Google).

[image: A close up of the wallpaper showing Hespprivs Hall]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

I doubt the wallpaper is "licensed" *but* I recognise most of the other big names on it so it seems odd to have a "made up" one on there too.

**What is Hespprivs Hall?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is apparently named the [Hesperius Hall](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hesperius_Hall)

> The Hesperius Hall is an antechamber to the main entrance of the Clock
>   Tower at Hogwarts Castle. It is located opposite the Vastus Vestibule
>   and can be seen on the Marauder's Map replica.

Comment: Ah, found it at the same time as you! I'd note though that unless I'm daft (quite likely) I don't know where they get the translation from.

Answer (score 6):

It would appear this is [Hesperius Hall](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hesperius_Hall) (translation done on the fandom wiki so no idea if it is accurate).

> The Hesperius Hall is an antechamber to the main entrance of the Clock Tower at Hogwarts Castle. It is located opposite the Vastus Vestibule and can be seen on the Marauder's Map replica.

It appears on the [official Marauder's Map replica](https://shop.wbstudiotour.co.uk/products/replica-marauders-map) from the films. See [this Pinterest post](https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/124060164709018086/) for an image of the relevant part of it (bottom left, to the left of the Clock Tower):

[image: Marauder's Map replica showing Hesperius Hall next to the clocktower]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

It apparently also appears in the film, *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, but from checking a few scenes I can't spot it so I imagine it appears in the credits.

Comment: In the screenshot of the map used in the question, you can clearly see the word "COURTYARD" which has a distinct U, different from the V they seem to use in "HESPERIVS HALL". (The question says it says "HESPPRIVS HALL" but I think it's just a random ink blot making the second E look like a P.) But in the image of the map in this answer, the map is clearly different, where courtyard looks like "COVRTYARD", and therefore with this map you can infer "HESPERIVS HALL" is supposed to be read "Hesperius Hall."